# MySQL GROUP BY and merge columns

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table that holds a **student_id** and a datetime timestamp (**log_time**) of when they arrived at school.

I have built a query that lists the student_id alongside the time they arrived for the current week. How can I combine the results so for example from the data below student_id 4211 shows on one line with the time in tuesday, wednesday and thursday? Using GROUP BY only shows one time. I need to somehow group by the student_id but combine the day times.

```
SELECT
    student_id,
    if( (DAYOFWEEK(log_time)=2)=0, '-', DATE_FORMAT(log_time,'%H:%i:%s') ) AS monday_time,
    if( (DAYOFWEEK(log_time)=3)=0, '-', DATE_FORMAT(log_time,'%H:%i:%s') ) AS tuesday_time,
    if( (DAYOFWEEK(log_time)=4)=0, '-', DATE_FORMAT(log_time,'%H:%i:%s') ) AS wednesday_time,
    if( (DAYOFWEEK(log_time)=5)=0, '-', DATE_FORMAT(log_time,'%H:%i:%s') ) AS thursday_time,
    if( (DAYOFWEEK(log_time)=6)=0, '-', DATE_FORMAT(log_time,'%H:%i:%s') ) AS friday_time
FROM
    tbl_student_register
WHERE
    YEARWEEK(`log_time`, 1) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE(), 1)
```

This will give the following result from my data

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT student_id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(log_time) = 2 THEN DATE_FORMAT(log_time, '%H:%i:%s') END) AS monday_time,
       . . .
FROM tbl_student_register
WHERE YEARWEEK(`log_time`, 1) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE(), 1) 
GROUP BY student_id;
```

The `MAX()` combines the values together.  If there is only one entry for a given date, then it will return that entry.  If there are multiple entries, you'll need to figure out the logic to handle that.